# "Плотность населения одной фавеллы составляет по 400 тысяч человек на каждую" - это ли называтся речевой избыточностью?

Tags: грамотная-речь, речевая-избыточность

> В самом Рио плотность населения одной фавеллы составляет по 400 тысяч
>   человек на каждую (см. фильм «Город Бога»).

Как быть с "по" и с "на каждую"? Просто выбросить?

Или я неправильно читаю, что бывает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Плотность населения измеряют в человеках на км², поэтому такая формулировка в любом случае не годится. Можно сказать так:

> В самом Рио население каждой фавелы составляет около 400 тысяч человек.

*Фавела* пишется с одной Л.

Comment: я бы добавил ***в среднем** составляет около 400 тысяч*, иначе можно сделать вывод, что все они примерно равны по численности.

Comment: Вообще-то, из фразы это и следует.) Иначе вообще тогда непонятно, как трактовать.

Comment: Смысл из  безграмотной речи трудно бывает извлечь. Но здравый смысл подсказывает, что фавелы, вероятно, всё-таки различаются по численности.

Comment: @ АртёмЛуговой. Тёмыч, ты гений, честь тебе и хвала! Но не за то, что вносишь необязательную правку (зачастую)! Ты спас меня с фавелой! Я проверяю сотни и тысячи не употребляемых мною единиц лексики, а чёртову "фавеЛЛу" пропустила, доверилась автору...

Comment: ))) Я рад!)))))